# Use the same facebook app for both android and iphone versions of the application

Tags: android, ios, facebook

I have created an android and iOS version of the same app and I want to share same facebook data with both apps.

example, if theres one user using the android app, he should be listed when checking the users list in the iOS version of the app.

But currently I'm getting a separate set of users for both apps. The same facebook user has to login in through both iOS and Android apps to make himself available in both versions

I use the same app key and the same facebook app.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Well this all comes down to how exactly you are determining if a user is online or not.  There are permissions available through the Facebook API that allows you to detect users online status. It is called [`online_presence` and `friend_online_presence`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/login/extended-permissions/). I can't see a reason that there would be a distinction between platforms with regard to online presence... It just doesn't make sense. I should note here that the online status of a user is in actual fact just the chat status, as mentioned in the documentation of the [user table](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/user/) -

> **online_presence** (*string*) - The user's Facebook Chat status. Returns a string, one of `active`,
>   `idle`, `offline`, or `error` (when Facebook can't determine presence
>   information on the server side). The query does not return the user's
>   Facebook Chat status when that information is restricted for privacy
>   reasons.

You could alternatively have an "online users" table in *your* database with a list of  users and on connect/disconnect, update that users record. Now your database will contain live data that you can query.